# SVD of two matrices A and B having the same right singular vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis

I saw this statement in a lecture note

> Assume the generalized SVD of matrices $A\in R^{m\times n}$ and $B\in R^{p\times n}$ given as:
>
> $$U^TAX = diag(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n),~ U^TU = I_m$$
> $$V^TBX = diag(\beta_1, ..., \beta_q),~ V^TV = I_p, ~q = min\{p, n\}$$

I found that the right singular value vectors of the SVD of matrices $A$ and $B$ here are a same matrix $X$. I don't know how to find the SVD like that. Is that any two matrices with the same number of columns can be decomposed via this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those notes do not refer to the "usual" SVD, but to the [**generalized SVD**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_singular_value_decomposition), which is a different decomposition of a pair of matrices (and does not require $X$ to be orthogonal, in particular).

For a quick introduction, you can check the Golub-Van Loan book, for instance.

Comment: I have been struggling for a few days failing to implement the GSVD algorithm.  Do you know where to find an available c implementation?

Comment: @Shindou I have only ever used [Matlab's library function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gsvd.html). There should be an implementation in LAPACK that you can use with a C wrapper, but I can't help you much with finding it.

Comment: There are several `R` packages, of which `geigen` is perhaps the easiest to use, which calculate the eigenvalues & vectors of matrix pairs. Mostly they call LAPACK